# Dart and third party CSS and JS frameworks

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, dart

I am gearing up to create my first web application and I've been reading a lot about [Google Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/). It looks like a very fun, exciting new approach to web development and I am strongly considering using it for my application.

There is one question that I've been unable to find a solid answer for, however: is it possible to use a CSS/JS framework with Dart? In this case, I'm interested in using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). I'd like to take advantage of the fantastic layout tools, buttons, and javascript modules it provides.

Would it be possible to use Dart and Bootstrap at the same time?
Do I even need to use Bootstrap? Does Dart already provide or make it easy to create what Bootstrap provides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your question. Yes, you can use Bootstrap with a Dart app. Bootstrap is mostly a set of CSS presets, patterns, and styles. There are a few JavaScript powered Bootstrap plugins for more interactive behavior. Depending on what you want to do, those JavaScript plugins can operate independently of your Dart app.

Dart does not bundle anything like Bootstrap. You could use Dart to replicate the Bootstrap plugins, but there isn't much need to do that.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! I'll need to do some more research on how to make Dart and JavaScript plugins co-exist nicely. You wouldn't happen to have a link to something that discusses this, would you? :)

Answer (score 3):

I created small sample. Use bootstrap into Dart.
https://github.com/ehr174/dartstrap

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [Bootjack](http://blog.rikulo.org/posts/2013/May/General/bootjack-and-dquery/) -- a Bootstrap port in Dart.